# C/C++ NaN resolution

Tags: c++, c, vector, double, nan

When I'm running some code I have to add up the elements of a vector and then renormalize. I'm getting NaN so I'm hoping to resolve this.

For example, when `x = [1,2,3]` is a `vector<double>` I compute `sum(x) = 6` and then find out what `x/6` is by setting `x[i] = x[i]/sum(x)` for all i in x. The problem is that x typically holds large doubles and sometimes when I compute `sum(x)` `(len(x)` is also very large by the way) I get NaN. How can I deal with this so that I do not get the NaN?

Changing it to store long double might work??

Comment: Can you provide code that reproduces the problem? Are you sure you do not have a `0/0`?

Comment: `long double` is platform-depended and ABI-depended. On x86 with x87 FPU you can use long double to get 80-bit precision. Also you can try `__float128` from modern gcc (4.7+, x86/x86_64), which implements [128-bit quad precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) in software.

Comment: In IEEE 754 arithmetic, you cannot produce a NaN by summing any number of non-NaN values, regardless of their size. If you are getting a NaN, there is some other problem. You should show a [self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org) of the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem occiasionally when I run things with a sister Python code. I'm optimizing a fairly jagged function so gradients may be very large one way or another. For example, I get things like

Comment: I have the same problem occasionally when I run things with a sister Python code. I'm optimizing a fairly jagged function so gradients may be very large one way or another. For example, my updates look like x = x*exp(-gradientvector) (here x was such that originally sum(x) = 1) and then I get sum(x) = 7.72968066938e+169. I then set x = x/sum(x) and this is OK. On the next iteration however, I get a blowup and sum(x) is set is inf in Python so that when the code runs and sets x = x/sum(x) and I display sum(x) now I don't see 1 but NaN. With the C++ code I get NaN when I look at the objective.

Comment: When I look at the objective value using this new vector x which gave NaNs in the sense that I talked about above.

Comment: Well, `inf/inf` will give you `-NaN`. It is really hard to tell without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your vectors do not bring a NaN with them? Btw - the "norm" you use is not non-negative for arbitrary vectors, are you sure you don't want to sum abs(x[i])?

Comment: I did not verify that but I will. Basically the vectors are all in a simplex, so all elements are between 0 and 1 inside the vector and each vector is such that sum(x)= 1. When I do updates like x = x*exp(-gradients) I might be getter very large entries in there, but then how do I try to fix that, potentially.

Comment: @user2370986 : Your mentioning of "simplex" rings a bell - construction of simplices can yield very annoying surprises. More often than not one presumes something that does simply not hold for arbitrary positions and gets a NaN somewhere mixed in.

Comment: Hey so I am iterating over source_word. The main problem code is:

Answer (score 0):

Check the data in the original vector. Some of them are probably NaN **before** the sum, and as a result you have sum(x)=`NaN`.